# Датасет Celeba неверный?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, opencv, dataset

есть датасет лиц Celeba, вот ссылка на него на kaggle:
**https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset**
В архиве также идёт несколько файлов с дополнительной информацией, в частности, файл **list_bbox_celeba.csv**, содержащий строки в формате:
**image_id,x_1,y_1,width,height**
Но эти точки не соответствуют ограничивающему прямоугольнику на изображении, для примера:
В датасете все изображения 178x218, но в первой же строке файла list_bbox_celeba содержится следующая строка:
**000001.jpg,95,71,226,313**
Тогда как такой высоты и подавно быть не может
Вот код визуализации прямоугольника:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
with open("list_bbox_celeba.csv") as file:
    points = file.readlines()[1].replace("\n", "").split(",")[1:]
    points = [int(point) for point in points]
box = cv2.rectangle(img, (points[0], points[1]), (points[0] + points[2], points[1] + points[3]), (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("img_box", box)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, это в датасете проблема, или я неправильно визуализирую?

Comment: Ну там же есть обсуждения https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset/discussion там у людей такие же проблемы, хотя кто-то пытался что-то сделать, но, похоже, датасет реально кривой судя по тому, что там пишут. Можно ещё кернелы посмотреть, что там у народа получается при EDA

Comment: У меня не получилось
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7EVK8r0v7...
Вот здесь развилка: скачать оригинальные или выровненные лица, выровненные прекрасно скачиваются, а скачивание архивов с оригинальными лицами:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7EVK8r0v7...
Успехов не даёт, так как любой архив из доступных после скачивания помечается как поломанный и не открывается